# How to generate a proportion table based on count table in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a count table such like:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(x=letters[1:3],
                y=sample(1:10, 3),
                z=sample(3:20, 3))%>%
    mutate(tot=rowSums(select(., -1)))
df
  x  y  z tot
1 a  3 20  23
2 b 10 13  23
3 c  2  7   9
```

How to quickly generate a proportion table like

```
  x     y     z tot
1 a 13.04 86.96 100
2 b 43.48 56.52 100
3 c 22.22 77.78 100
```

Comment: Try: `df[,-1] / df$tot * 100`

Comment: This is another option: `df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~./tot*100)`, that will skip any non numeric columns wherever they are on your dataset.

Comment: That's decent code. Thanks

Comment: @AntoniosK, would you mind put your code as an answer? +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, ~./tot*100)

#   x        y        z tot
# 1 a 13.04348 86.95652 100
# 2 b 43.47826 56.52174 100
# 3 c 22.22222 77.77778 100
```

which will update only your numeric variables, wherever they exist in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

## Your code

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(x=letters[1:3],
               y=sample(1:10, 3),
               z=sample(3:20, 3))%>%
  mutate(tot=rowSums(select(., -1)))
df
  x  y  z tot
1 a  3 20  23
2 b 10 13  23
3 c  2  7   9
```

## Proportion dataframe

```
proportion_df<-cbind(x=df$x,df[,-1] / df$tot * 100)
proportion_df
  x        y        z tot
1 a 13.04348 86.95652 100
2 b 43.47826 56.52174 100
3 c 22.22222 77.77778 100
```